# Display the list of my twitter followers in ios 5 app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, twitter

I am building a demo app which is based off twitter. I already built a twitter login, but I want it also display the people I follow. Is there any way to get the list of people I am following and display it? Thanks So Much in Advance!!!

Comment: It's fantastic that you're working on all these projects, but you do need to start doing a bit of research yourself before posting questions.  What have you tried so far?  Have you checked out https://dev.twitter.com/docs ?

Answer (score 0):

You will find what you need on the:

dev.twitter.com/docs

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWRequestClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010942

WWDC 2011 Section 124